# Different tickets to and from Russia

Tags: customs-and-immigration, russia

I will be travelling from Pakistan to Russia and to Egypt thereafter. I have already made a Moscow-Cairo booking on Egyptair. I recently contacted an agent to book Lahore-Moscow for me on Etihad. According to him, if I book two separate tickets, the Russian authority will cause a problem at immigration. I wanted to know how credible the information is.

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you have a Russian visa?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have your Russian tourist visa, you shouldn't have any trouble. The immigration officers at Point of Entry do not look at your return flight, although they could ask to see one. They normally just verify your visa/passport/dates/photo and stamp it. I've never had Russian authorities ask for anything more than my visa and passport. I have been stopped at the exit and questioned about how much currency I have with me, but never have they asked about return flights.

Comment: Do they not have access to the passenger's itinerary through their computer systems?  If so, maybe they're not asking about return flights because they can already see that you have one.

Comment: @phoog how would they know your itinerary? they only deal with immigrants, not airlines? I've never had anyone "verify" any flights to or from Russia. Not even at the Russian Embassy when getting their visa in my passport. They only care about your visa and the dates matching up. They really don't care how you get there.

Comment: In some countries I'm familiar with (mainly the US and the UK), airlines supply passenger manifests to the immigration authorities, and the officer sees the passenger's record after scanning the passport or entering the passport details.  The record can have quite a lot of information, including the entire itinerary of that booking.  So if there's a return-ticket requirement (as there is for visa waiver program travelers in the US), the officer may not need to ask about tickets to see that one exists.

Comment: @phoog Russia is not one of those countries -- the visa application asks for a million things, but your flight details are *not* on the list.

Comment: @jpatokal not one of what countries?  The countries that require return tickets, or the countries where border officers have access to arriving passengers' PNRs?

Comment: @Calchas the OP doesn't specify if its transit only. Is that a normal route for transit only? I have no idea. My answer is for the specific question. Last time I checked, Pakistan and Egypt are much closer to each other than Russia. Why would you travel that far away to Russia, for transit only, is beyond me?

Comment: @AussieJoe Well you're totally right. Don't know why I thought this was a separate ticket transit. Ignore me.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (I've lived in Moscow for 40 years), it is highly unlikely you will have any problems with Russian authorities.